# NMap --script memcached-info not working for UDP

Tags: nmap

I have a brand new installed memcached on ubuntu server 18.04.4 listening on UDP and TCP

NMap 7.60 works fine for me, for TCP, as follows:

sudo nmap --script memcached-info -p 11211 172.17.208.109

The nmap flag to run as UDP is -sU

tcpdump shows I don't get an answer from the NMap server when using UDP, as follows:

sudo nmap -sU --script memcached-info -p 11211 172.17.208.109

Does the --script memcached-info support UDP?  If UDP is supported, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It apparently is not supported.  So one workaround is the following:

printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00stats\r\n' | nc -s spoof-ip -u target-ip 11211

Before doing the above, you should add the spoof-ip address as a 2nd IP address on your interface, with something like the following:

However, assuming the spoofed IP address is 1.2.3.4, you should enter the following since symbolic names are not supported by ip address add:

ip address add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth0